# Stress-energy tensor a total divergence?

Tags: momentum, conservation-laws, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Given the energy-momentum tensor $\Theta^{\mu}_{\,\,\nu}$, I'd like to consider the scenario in which it can be written as a total derivative
$$\Theta^{\mu}_{\,\,\nu}=\partial_{\alpha}\eta^{\alpha\mu}_{\,\,\,\,\,\nu}$$
$\Theta^{\mu}_{\,\,\nu}$ is ambiguous up to terms $\Theta'^{\mu}_{\,\,\nu}=\Theta^{\mu}_{\,\,\nu}+\partial_{\alpha}\chi^{\alpha\mu}_{\,\,\,\,\,\nu}$ with $\chi^{\alpha\mu}_{\,\,\,\,\,\nu}$ antisymmetric in $\alpha$ and $\mu$, and so $\eta^{\alpha\mu}_{\,\,\,\,\,\nu}$ can always be taken to be symmetric in $\alpha$ and $\mu$. It doesn't appear to be possible to reduce it further.

I am wondering if something can be said physically about this scenario? Perhaps something about the momentum $P_{\nu}=\int d^3x\Theta^0_{\,\,\nu}$ and how fields $\phi(x)$ depend on spacetime?

An observation is that $P_{\nu}=\partial_{0}\big(\int d^3x\eta^{00}_{\,\,\,\,\,\nu}\big)$ is a total time derivative. I'm not sure if this has physical significance.

Comment: This setup looks pretty similar to topological field theory.

Comment: @ConnorBehan it's interesting that you say that. But can I ask why you thought that? Typically topological field theories are said to have vanishing stress energy tensors.

Comment: In the constructions by Witten, it only vanishes after you restrict to a certain cohomology. Before that, the stress tensor is exact with respect to a supercharge. This is almost like a total derivative except it would be a SUSY covariant derivative.

Comment: @ConnorBehan This is the form of the stress tensor I arrived at by assuming a global GL(4,R) spacetime invariance. Not quite a topological field theory, but such a theory cannot depend on a metric.